# Selecting rows of a dataframe fullfilling an specific condition in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

First of all, I have to say that this is my first post. Despite of having look for the answer using the search toolbox it might be possible that I passed over the right topic without realizing myself, so just in case sorry for that.

Having said that, my problem is the following one:

- I have a data table composed by several columns.
- I have to select the
  rows that are fullfilling one specific condition ex.
  which(DT_$var>value, arr.ind = T)) or which(DT_$var>value &&
  DT_$var2>value2, arr.ind = T))
- I have to keep these columns in a new
  data frame.

My approach was the following one but it is not working, probably because I did not understand the loops correctly:

```
while (i in nrow(DT)) {
    if(DT$var[i]>value){
        DT_aux[i]=DT[i]
        i<-i+1
    }

}
Error in if (DT$value[i] > 45) { : argument is of length zero
```

I hope that you can help me

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good chance that you want to use `dplyr` and it's `filter` function. It would work like this:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% filter(var>value && var2>value2)
```

You don't need to use `DT$var` and `DT$var2` here; `dplyr` knows what you mean when you refer to variables.

You can, of course, do the same with base R, but this kind of work is exactly what `dplyr` was made for, so sticking with base R, in this case, is just masochism.

Comment: Dear Thomas, 

Your solution worked like a charm, however for some reason that I do not understand I have to specify the logical operator as & instead of &&.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The filter function considers the columns as vectors, I guess, so you have to use the vector version of the logical operators. I usually just separate the conditions with commas, though, as that works as logical and.